# Can the Intel HD Graphics 515 be used as an OpenCL compute device?

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, intel, gpu-driver, opencl

Under Windows, there are drivers that support this chip for OpenCL. Do the Linux drivers support this as well?

Comment: I do not have the device at hand to try it. If you have a Ubuntu system (better 16.04) there with you (also a live one is good) install  `mesa-utils` and run `glxinfo | grep -i opencl`. This will tell if it supports it and at which version.

Comment: I get no result, although the chip should support OpenCL. Is there a driver for that?

Comment: In theory the driver for the skylake chipsets is already in 16.04...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that chip does support OpenCL. Check this out: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers

Install it and it works.